# Combining string modification and concatenation in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

So my problem is to take a string in haskell and to modify it so that if there are certain characters, they are changed to other characters, and I have created a helper function to do this, however  there is one case where if the character is '!' then it become '!!!111oneone', so i figure to do this you would need to concatenate the current string with '!!111oneone', the trouble is that my function was working with chars however to do this we would need to work with the string, how would you combine this, ie a helper to modify the chars if necessary and implementing the conversion if there is a '!'.

Here is what i have so far

```
convert :: String -> String
convert [] = []
convert (x:xs) =
| x == '!'  = !helper
| otherwise = converthelper x
```

Comment: You can use `++` to concatenate strings. If `c` is a single char, you can use `[c]` to turn it into a string (if you need to). Instead `c : s` prepends char `c` to the string `s`.

Comment: ok thanks ill try to implement that!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your helper is something like

```
helper :: Char -> String
helper '!' = "!!!111oneone"
helper c = [c]
```

then you can use `concatMap` to map `helper` over each character in your string, and then concatenate the results into a single string.

```
convert :: String -> String
convert = concatMap helper
-- convert msg = concatMap helper msg
```

The trick is that your helper promotes *every* character to a list of characters; most characters just become the corresponding one-character string, but `!` becomes something more.

(Note that `concatMap` forms the basis of the `Monad` instance for lists. You could also write `convert msg = msg >>= helper`.)

Comment: Congrats, you've just defined an L-System. (Ok, technically you also need a starting string.)

Comment: Heh, I don't think I ever knew there was a formal name for that process.

Comment: (Of course, in this case we're stopping after one round of replacements.)

Comment: This is a very nice approach, but I fear it is too high-level for the OP who is a beginner and did not know about `++`, which is more basic than `concatMap`.

Comment: Yep. `iterate (>>= helper)` will give you the whole sequence.

Comment: I was assuming he already had a helper with type `Char -> Char`, which meant he had something like `convert (x:xs) = helper x : convert xs` or `convert msg = map helper msg`.